# Very simple homomorphism question of groups.

Tags: group-theory

I am reading a very basic proof about group theory.

> Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism of a group $G$ into a group $G'$. Then $e \in G$ being the identity $\implies \phi(e) = e' \in G'$ being the identity in $G'$

The sketch of the proof goes like this

> $$\phi(a) = \phi(ae) = \phi(a)\phi(e).$$ Multiplying on the left by $\phi(a)^{-1}$, we see that $e' = \phi(e).$

This was taken from Fraleigh.

Now there are few things I am not quite getting.

1. How do we know $\phi^{-1}$ exists? Is it because $\phi^{-1} \in G$ and as $G$ is a group, $\phi^{-1}$ is well-defined?
2. how do we know $\phi(a)^{-1}\phi(a) = e'$? And am I correct to assume $\phi(a)\phi(a)^{-1} \neq e'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi(a)^{-1}$ is not the same as $\phi^{-1}(a)$. The former is just the inverse of the element $\phi(a) \in G'$, so $\phi(a)\phi(a)^{-1} = e'$ holds by definition!

Comment: Oh that's interesting…how did I mix them up?? Anyways, was my conjecture on (2) correct? I don't want to come up with a counterexample right now…

Comment: @sidht Careful on (2). is $G'$ abelian? That is, I am conjecturing it is true in the case when it is, and not necessarily true otherwise. Sorry that is I am conjecturing you are correct when it is not abelian. Lol, i just noticed that too. ergo the reversal.

Comment: @drawnonward, ah right, that's how I initially came up with the conjecture. I misread (2). I thought i had an equal sign, but it has an unequal sign.